# Bootstrap modal populated by selected row in table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The code below works fine on my computer, however when I am trying it on different workstations it does not work unless you do a hard refresh SHIFT + F5 then it will work but, when the page is reloaded it will go back to not working. Any help if you can tell me where this script is wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
function run() {
var table = document.getElementById('call-logs-table');
var rows = table.rows; 
for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
rows[i].onclick = function (event) {
var cells = this.cells;

var person_contacted = cells[0].innerHTML;
var date = cells[1].innerHTML;
var c_purpose = cells[2].innerHTML;
var c_notes = cells[3].innerHTML;
var sales_rep = cells[4].innerHTML;
var timestamp = cells[5].innerHTML;
var potential = cells[6].innerHTML;
var catalog_num = cells[7].innerHTML;
var dateplanner_num = cells[8].innerHTML;
var calendar_num  = cells[9].innerHTML;


document.getElementById('call-log-title').innerHTML = 'Call Log Entered at ' + timestamp + ' by ' + sales_rep;

document.getElementById('lbl_contact').innerHTML = person_contacted;
document.getElementById('lbl_date').innerHTML = date;
document.getElementById('lbl_catalogs').innerHTML = catalog_num;
document.getElementById('lbl_calendars').innerHTML = calendar_num;
document.getElementById('lbl_planners').innerHTML = dateplanner_num;
document.getElementById('lbl_purpose').innerHTML = c_purpose;
document.getElementById('lbl_notes').innerHTML = c_notes;
document.getElementById('lbl_potential').innerHTML = potential;

};
}
}
window.onload = function() { run(); }
```

Comment: It blows my mind how it works 100% on my computer and not on anyone else's without a force reload of the page.